# How to get URL parameter in Express?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-router

I have a problem with getting URL parameter in Express.
On the client (Angular) I define state (ui.router) and send URL (id) with new state:

```
.state('home.detail', {
  url: '/:id',
  templateUrl: 'views/detail.html',
  controller: 'DetailController'
 });
```

On the backend, I'm trying to get this URL(id)

```
app.get('/api/:id', function(req,res){
    var id = req.query.id;
    console.log(id);

    var queryString = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE table.ID=id";
    //add to a callback
    connection.query(queryString, function (error, results) {
        if(error) {
            throw error;
        }
        else { 
            // send JSON object to the client
            res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
            //console.log(res);
        }
    });
});
```

but I got `undefined`value of id (console.log(id)).
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer solved your problem :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use this instead :

```
var id = req.params.id;
```

- `req.params` contains route parameters (in the path portion of the
  URL)
- `req.query` contains the URL query parameters (after the ? in
  the URL).

Answer (score 1):

The `:id` gets put in the params object in the request. So, all you have to do to get it is do:

```
var id = req.params.id;
```

Also, when you build your `queryString` you need to pass it the value of id instead of a string called "id". You would have to do something like this:

```
var queryString = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE table.ID=" + id;
```

Comment: I tried with `req.params.id` and I changed the query to the `var queryString = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.ID=" + id;` and I get the Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':id' at line 1. Do I need to use some URL parser? Thanks

Comment: If that is a MySQL error than you would just need to reformat your query string however the version of MySQL wants it. The query parser in an expressJS context is used to parse our query params in the url. So, if the user made a call to 'example.com?id=5&name=hello' the query parser would parse out 'id' and 'name' for you in the req.query object (Just to give an example).

Comment: I have installed [node-mysql](http://https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#escaping-query-values) and the new format is: `connection.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = ?', [ id ], function (error, results) {  
  if(error) {
   throw error;
  }
  else { 
   // send JSON object to the client
        res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
        //console.log(res);
  }
 });`  The error is gone, but instead of value (1), I got a name in console.log (:id) when I run the app. It is interesting when I try to acces manually to API (http://localhost/api/:1) I get data and id (1) is entered in the log.